# Understanding Stagnation point in pitot fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What is stagnation point in fluid mechanics.
At the open end of the pitot tube the velocity of the fluid becomes zero.But that should result in accumulation of liquid inside the pipe which is not possible. Does streamline terminates or it changes its direction at the open end of pitot tube?

Answer (score 4):

A stagnation looks like [this](https://www.princeton.edu/~maelabs/hpt/mechanics/mecha_46.htm):

[image]

Fluid does not accumulate at the stagnation point; it flows away one way or the other.  Close to the stagnation point, it flows very slowly and the closer you get, the slower it flows.

The diagram for the stagnation point over a pitot probe looks [very similar](http://www.efunda.com/designstandards/sensors/pitot_tubes/pitot_tubes_theory.cfm):

[image]

Again, all the fluid is moving.  It is that the closer you get to the stagnation point, the *slower* that it moves.

Comment: So can we assume velocity of fluid at stagnation point approximately to be zero while applying bernoulli equation

Comment: Yes, the closer you get to the stagnation point, the the closer the speed gets to being zero.

Comment: In the direction does stagnation line terminates or it changes direction